# Remote Path en Deployment Manager de RAD Studio Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi, deployment

En el Deployment Manager de RAD Studio Delphi 10.4, ¿cómo puedo indicar el remote path para un fichero a c:\ProgramData\MiAplicacion en Windows?

Mi programa utiliza una base de datos mdb y funciona normalmente si lo instalo en cualquier directorio "normal". No obstante, si instalo el fichero mdb en el directorio del programa (dentro de *Program Files*), el programa no pude leer el fichero mdb, por ello necesito instalar este fichero en una carpeta de *ProgramData* para mi aplicación.

Si escribo la ruta *c:\ProgramData\Miaplicacion* en el remote path del Deployment manager, simplemente combina esta ruta con la del programa (o sea, intenta instalarlo en *c:\Program Files\MiAplicacion\C:\ProgramData\MiAplicacion*).

Comment: Comenzar diciendo que el Deployment Manager cobra más sentido con aplicaciones que se despliegan en otros sistemas operativos. Para Windows, yo no lo utilizaría para desplegar una base de datos, sino que usualmente hago un instalador que es el que se encarga de ello, por ejemplo con Inno Setup. Si insistes en usar el Deployment Manager, entiendo que este no soporta indicar rutas del sistema, si lo dejas como `./`, la ruta es relativa al "scratch directory" del PA: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Deployment_Manager

Comment: La carpeta por defecto es: C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Profiles

Comment: Tienes razón con Inno Setup, jachguate, pero para evitar los molestos avisos de Windows de que el fichero exe puede contener virus, estoy intentado publicar mi aplicación en Microsoft Store. Ellos quieren un fichero msix y por ello le añado los otros ficheros del programa con el Deployment Manager.

Answer (score 1):

He descubierto una solución. La comparto por si es útil a alguien más.

Microsoft Store no guarda los programas en ProgramFiles, sino en el directorio WindowsApps. Este directorio es de los más protegidos del sistema; es muy difícil escribir o modificar nada en él, y no es conveniente. Los datos, ficheros temporales, etc deben guardarse en un directorio específico de ProgramData, el cual es fácilmente accesible.

No he encontrado la manera de que el Deployment Manager de Delphi copie ficheros en ProgramData, pero he encontrado esta alternativa:

1. Con el Deployment Manager, instalo el fichero mdb (y cualquier otro fichero que deba escribirse durante la ejecución del programa) en el directorio del programa.
2. En el FormCreate de la primera ventana que se abre en el programa, leo el directorio del programa con ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)). Ojo: GetDir no funciona aquí.
3. Compruebo si existe el directorio c:\ProgramData\MiAplicacion (DirectoryExists). Si no existe, lo creo con ForceDirectories(c:\ProgramData\MiAplicacion)
4. Copio en este directorio (con CopyFile) el fichero mdb y los demás que deban escribirse durante la ejecución.
5. Leo y escribo estos ficheros en el directorio que he creado en ProgramData. Me olvido del original que está en el directorio del programa.

Y ya he conseguido que el programa funcione. Lo han aceptado y publicado en Microsoft Store!